# Ionic2 Error using AngularFire and Firebase: Uncaught (in promisse): This is null

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm currently learning Ionic2 and Angular and I'm trying to use Firebase as database for the application. The first thing I'm trying to do is to use AngularFire to login using Firebase Email authentication. Code below:

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Home } from '../../home/home';
import { SignUp } from '../signup/signup'
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2'
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class Login {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public af: AngularFire) {
  }
  public loginWithEmail(username: string, password: string) {
    this.af.auth.login({
      email: username,
      password: password,
    },
    {
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }).then(function() {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(Home);
    })
  }
}
```

login.html

```
...
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Senha</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <button ion-button block (click)="loginWithEmail(userName, password)">Login</button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
...
```

But then, when I click on the button, and call `loginWithEmail()` method, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this is null
Login.prototype.loginWithEmail/<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:83566:13
O</g</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9653
NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:37511:28
O</g</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9591
O</d</e.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7000
h/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4659
O</g</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10273
NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:37502:28
O</g</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10201
O</d</e.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7618
i@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3700
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I still don't know why it works that way and not in the other...
>   could someone explain me?

The answer is because of [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). When using the `this` keyword inside a function like `function(){...}`, the `this` keyword references the function itself (and the `navCtrl` is not defined in that function).

One of the most important aspects of the arrow functions is that

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and **does not bind its own this**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

So when using the `this` keyword inside of () => {...}, it will still reference the component instance (which has a `navCtrl` property defined), so everything works as expected.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @LuanGonçalvesBarbosa may I ask why my answer was first accepted and now is not the selected answer anymore?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I was testing something... rs

Comment: @LuanGonçalvesBarbosa np, just wanted to know if there was something to add to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have just found a way to get it working: I have just changed:

(on login.ts)

this:

```
.then(function() {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(Home);
})
```

to this:

```
.then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot(Home))
```

But I still don't know why it works that way and not in the other... could someone explain me?